# How to trim or remove empty lines on text element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to delete or trim empty lines left when a function removes a particular lines from the element in jquery.....

this is the function which creates empty line after removing all words from the line....

```
   $(".text").html(function(i,t){
      return t.replace(x,'');
   });
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;"><input type='checkbox' name='1' value='Value1' ></input></td>
      <td style="width:200px;"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;"><input type='checkbox' name='2' value='Value2' ></input></td>
      <td style="width:200px;"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how your text will look a like?
What exactly are you looking for? can you explain in brief?

Comment: actually i created a list where a user can select items by checking the chekboxes... so when a user selects an item by checking the checkbox, the name of the item is printed on the list element..... but somehow if a user uncheck the selected checkbox... i made a function to remove the name of that item from the list element... but after deleting the name it keeps the line empty which covers unwanted space.

Comment: so what's the problem with this?are you looking for something like if user uncheck that check box then that item should also get removed from list?
please provide your HTML code too.

Comment: i just want when the user uncheck the checkbox the name should be deleted from the list element as well as the empty line that it left behind...
because when a user selects new item... the name of the item is printed on next new line in the list element...

Comment: <table>
<tr><td style="text-align:left;"><input type='checkbox' name='1' value='Value1' ></input></td><td style="width:200px;"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left;"><input type='checkbox' name='2' value='Value2' ></input></td><td style="width:200px;"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>



<table border="1">
<tr><td><div class="text" id="text"></div></td><td class="value"></td></tr>
</table>

Comment: I've posted my answer and Im not seeing any line spacing issue.

Comment: You should not post your code in comment, simply you can edit your question and add code over there only.

Comment: I've posted my ans, verify it and let me know if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Something like this?**

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    if(this.checked)
    {        $("#lstElements").append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).val()+"</option>");
    }
    else
    {
        
    $("#lstElements option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1">1st</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2">2nd</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3">3rd</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="4" value="4">4th</input>
<select multiple="true" id="lstElements">
    <option>select</option>
</select>
```